# How to change the text of the legend of a choropleth map in Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, geopandas

I get one choropleth map using the following code:

```
%matplotlib inline

import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import pysal as ps
import geopandas as gpd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as pet

imd_shp = 'desktop/sgfwu/E07000222_IMD/shapefiles/E07000222.shp'
imd = gpd.read_file(imd_shp)
imd = imd.set_index('LSOA11CD') 
imd.plot(column='imd_score', scheme='fisher_jenks', alpha=0.8, k=7,
         colormap=plt.cm.Blues, legend=True, axes=ax1)
```

The result is:

[image]

But how can I change the text of the legend to the words like the map below, rather than numbers?

[image]

Comment: Which library are you using for this?

Comment: I'm a rookie programmer so I'm not sure about what actually it is >.< All libraries I 'm using are seaborn, pandas, pysal, geopandas, bumpy and matplotlib.pyplot.

Comment: Should I provide more codes?

Comment: Yes, a slightly longer fragment that actually produces the chart would be nice.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have added them in the question. Here is a related course: http://darribas.org/gds15/content/labs/lab_04.html

Comment: I suspect you could find something useful in [matplotlib legend guide](http://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html), but I don't have a complete answer. See how label names can be given.

Comment: Hmmm. I might be wrong, but it looks like you're skipping the code that has the plot creation. Where is i`md_plot` defined? I suspect the answer to that will help find the docs needed to solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for 9000's help. I was reading the guide but still has no correct idea >3<.

Comment: Oh, it should be imd.plot rather than imd_plot. I write it wrong and change it now.

Comment: @FanWu: your example is still not reproducible (where do you define `ax1`?), so try to give a minimum reproducible one and indicate the version of geopandas you are using. What does `ax1.get_legend_handles_labels()` give you? Setting `ax1.legend(handles, labels)` by keeping the handles and just changing the labels might do the trick.

Answer (score 6):

This question has been here for a while, but I just had the same problem. This solved it for me:

```
leg = ax1.get_legend()
leg.get_texts()[0].set_text('New label 1')
leg.get_texts()[1].set_text('New label 2')
```

and so on for as many labels as you want to change.