# Custom legend labels - geopandas.plot()

Tags: plot, geopandas, legend-properties

A colleague and I have been trying to set custom legend labels, but so far have failed. Code and details below - any ideas much appreciated!

Notebook: [toy example uploaded here](https://gist.github.com/claytonrsh/3a3fd878a8b935b3cf720fabf7187a11)

Goal: change default rate values used in the legend to corresponding percentage values

Problem: cannot figure out how to access the legend object or pass `legend_kwds` to `geopandas.GeoDataFrame.plot()`

Data: [KCMO metro area counties](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/claytonrsh/76313da528e1116a959d7401b8b7afed/raw/8247f2fcf3fb08aa1f3aa7b236fba3013602dc9d/kcmo_counties.geojson)

**Excerpts from toy example**

Step 1: read data

```
# imports
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
# read data
gdf = gpd.read_file('kcmo_counties.geojson')
```

Option 1 - get legend from `ax` as [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33762891/how-to-change-the-text-of-the-legend-of-a-choropleth-map-in-python):

```
ax = gdf.plot('val', legend=True)
leg = ax.get_legend()
print('legend object type: ' + str(type(leg))) # <class NoneType>
plt.show()
```

Option 2: pass `legend_kwds` dictionary - I assume I'm doing something wrong here (and clearly don't fully understand the underlying details), but the `_doc_` from [Geopandas's plotting.py](https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/blob/master/geopandas/plotting.py) - for which [GeoDataFrame.plot() is simply a wrapper](https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/blob/master/geopandas/geodataframe.py) - does not appear to come through...

```
# create number of tick marks in legend and set location to display them
import numpy as np
numpoints = 5
leg_ticks = np.linspace(-1,1,numpoints)

# create labels based on number of tickmarks
leg_min = gdf['val'].min()
leg_max = gdf['val'].max()
leg_tick_labels = [str(round(x*100,1))+'%' for x in np.linspace(leg_min,leg_max,numpoints)]
leg_kwds_dict = {'numpoints': numpoints, 'labels': leg_tick_labels}

# error "Unknown property legend_kwds" when attempting it:
f, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(6,6))
gdf.plot('val', legend=True, ax=ax, legend_kwds=leg_kwds_dict)
```

**UPDATE**
Just came across [this conversation](https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/pull/434) on adding in `legend_kwds` - and this other [bug?](https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/issues/694) which clearly states `legend_kwds` was not in most recent release of GeoPandas (v0.3.0). Presumably, that means we'll need to compile from the GitHub `master` source rather than installing with pip/conda...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've just come across this issue myself. After following your link to the Geopandas source code, it appears that the colourbar is added as a second axis to the figure. so you have to do something like this to access the colourbar labels (assuming you have plotted a chloropleth with `legend=True`):

```
# Get colourbar from second axis
colourbar = ax.get_figure().get_axes()[1]
```

Having done this, you can manipulate the labels like this:

```
# Get numerical values of yticks, assuming a linear range between vmin and vmax:
yticks = np.interp(colourbar.get_yticks(), [0,1], [vmin, vmax])

# Apply some function f to each tick, where f can be your percentage conversion
colourbar.set_yticklabels(['{0:.2f}%'.format(ytick*100) for ytick in yticks])
```

Answer (score -1):

This can be done by passing key-value pairs to dictionary argument `legend_kwds`:

```
gdf.plot(column='col1', cmap='Blues', alpha=0.5, legend=True, legend_kwds={'label': 'FOO', 'shrink': 0.5}, ax=ax)
```